# Laravel PayPal agreement-execute error on return url

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I have two questions, first about the error, Laravel 8.20.1 + Paypal SDK v1.

App Routes:

```
Route::get('/agreement/execute', [PaymentController::class, 'agreementExecute']);
Route::post('/agreement/create', [PaymentController::class, 'subscribeMonthly']);
```

Admin Routes:

```
Route::prefix('paypal')->name('plan.')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/monthly/create', [PrivatePaypal::class, 'createMonthly'])
    Route::get('/list', [PrivatePaypal::class, 'showPlans'])
    Route::get('/plan/{plan}', [PrivatePaypal::class, 'plan'])
    Route::get('/delete', [PrivatePaypal::class, 'deletePlan'])
});
```

Created plan:

[Created plan image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zz4DN.png)

Plan code:

```
public function createMonthly() {
    $plan = new \PayPal\Api\Plan();
    $plan->setName('Monthly')
        ->setDescription('Activate partnership for one month.')
        ->setType('INFINITE'); // or FIXED: The plan has a fixed number of payment cycles

    $paymentDefinition = new \PayPal\Api\PaymentDefinition();
    $paymentDefinition->setName('Monthly Payments')
        ->setType('REGULAR') // or TRIAL
        ->setFrequency('Month') // or WEEK, DAY, YEAR, MONTH
        ->setFrequencyInterval("1") // The interval at which the customer is charged. Value cannot be greater than 12 months
        ->setAmount(new \PayPal\Api\Currency(array('value' => 20, 'currency' => 'USD')));
        // ->setCycles("12")

    $merchantPreferences = new \PayPal\Api\MerchantPreferences();
    $merchantPreferences->setReturnUrl(route('account.agreement',['success'=>'true'])) 
    ->setCancelUrl(route('account.agreement',['success'=>'false'])) 
    ->setAutoBillAmount("yes") 
    ->setInitialFailAmountAction("CONTINUE") 
    ->setMaxFailAttempts("0")
    ->setSetupFee(new \PayPal\Api\Currency(array('value' => config('settings.price_monthly'), 'currency' => 'USD'))) 
    ;

    $plan->setPaymentDefinitions(array($paymentDefinition));
    $plan->setMerchantPreferences($merchantPreferences);
    try {
        $createdPlan = $plan->create($this->apiContext);
    } catch(\Exception $ex) {
        print_r($ex->getMessage());
        die();
    }
    // dd($createdPlan);
    $this->activatePlan($createdPlan);
}
```

After I send data with the form

```
<form action="https://site.test/agreement/create" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="XSM2gxx0Cqs5dlloYScQfl2GdeGqrz4lkWLfm42a">             
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="P-0UV961714R317531UT5H72WI">
    <button class="button compact">Activate</button>
</form>
```

After succesful redirect to paypal with all data, i click accept (sandbox) and after that i get succesfull rerict back, redirect functions:

```
 if (!empty($request->input('success')))
    {
        $success = $request->input('success');
        if ($success && !empty($request->input('token')))
        {
            $token = $request->input('token');
            $agreement = new \PayPal\Api\Agreement();

            
            try {
                // Execute agreement
                $agreement->execute($token, $this->apiContext);
              } catch (PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
                    print_r($ex->getMessage());  
                    echo $ex->getCode();
                    echo $ex->getData();
                  print_r($ex->getData());
                die($ex);
              } catch (Exception $ex) {
                // die($ex);
              }
```

And when `$agreement->execute` runs I get errors with no detailed information.

Form subscribe function:

```
public function subscribeMonthly(Request $request) {
     $id = $request->id;
     $agreement = new \PayPal\Api\Agreement();
     $agreement->setName('Monthly subscription')
     ->setDescription('Activate partnership for one month.') 
     ->setStartDate(Carbon::now()->addMonth()->toIso8601String());

     $plan = new \PayPal\Api\Plan();
     $plan->setId($id);
    $agreement->setPlan($plan);

    $payer = new \PayPal\Api\Payer();
    $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');
    $agreement->setPayer($payer);

    try {
        $agreement = $agreement->create($this->apiContext);
        $approvalUrl = $agreement->getApprovalLink();
    } catch(\Exception $ex) {
        print_r($ex->getMessage());
        die();
    }

    return redirect($approvalUrl);
        
 }
```

Error is : **PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException
Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-agreements/EC-1LE052463N345662M/agreement-execute.
https://am.test/account/agreement?ba_token=BA-9X735270PX851462W&success=true&token=EC-1LE052463N345662M**

I reviewed a lot of tutorials, re-read the code in PayPal guides several times. I'm new to this and can't figure out what the reason is, it just doesn't work for me. I do everything one to one.
No subscriptions are created in the buyer account or by the administrator, everything is empty.

And the second question, Paypal writes that v1 is deprecated. How can I use the second version with a checkout v2 for subscriptions and where can I find detailed guides with the Laravel about this question.
It's hard for me to fully understand API and code not created by myself, I create a big project on my own, but stuck a few days with that PayPal error. Thank you for reading so much of what I have written, I hope for your support.

Comment: Make sure the DEBUG flag is on, and writing to a log. That will often help point out what the actual issue is. I was just attempting to move from v1 SDK to the Checkout SDK, but since Checkout still uses the v1 SDK, I just decided to stick with my original code.

Comment: Thanks, a forget to get look at log, there are somw stack trace and [2021-05-25 17:50:08] local.ERROR: Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-agreements/EC-61376229AX2881348/agreement-execute. {"userId":34,"exception":"[object] (PayPal\\Exception\\PayPalConnectionException(code: 400): Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-agreements/EC-61376229AX2881348/agreement-execute. at C:\\laragon\\www\\am\\vendor\\paypal\
est-api-sdk-php\\lib\\PayPal\\Core\\PayPalHttpConnection.php:207)

Comment: See if there's a separate PayPal log. I have one set up in my config, which is passed to the ApiContext when it's created. `'log.LogEnabled'=>true,
     'log.FileName' => storage_path() . '/logs/paypal_'.date('Y-m-d').'.log',
     'log.LogLevel' => 'DEBUG',`

Comment: Thanks a lot, its a good idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PayPal-PHP-SDK is deprecated, and **not compatible** with the current version of [PayPal Subscriptions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/). You should not be using it for anything.

Instead, integrate directly with the necessary Product, Plan, and subscription management API calls described in that Subscriptions documentation. (Plus webhooks, if desired--to be notified of future [subscription events](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions))

You can also manage Products and Plans manually in the receiver account:

- Sandbox: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/billing/plans
- Live: https://www.paypal.com/billing/plans

Comment: Thank you so much, you are my savior! It took a long time to just create everything in one minute. Tell me about the webhook, I haven't fully figured out how it works. I need to create a webhook BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CANCELLED, BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.SUSPENDED, BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.PAYMENT.FAILED that will knock on my controller, and I accept the data and remove it already working?

Comment: The way webhooks works is you 'create' one to subscribe to particular events (or all events), and then you'll receive a post from PayPal to the webhook listener URL you specified, whenever those events occur.  You can verify the webhook is genuinely from PayPal by posting it back to the webhook verification service, or cryptographically verifying the signature, but this is not so necessariy for cancelled/suspended/failed events (more useful for activation events, or payment events).